# psql pgadmin Procedure error column "trip" does not exist LINE 7: CALL example2(Trip)

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, procedure

I want to create a stored procedure in pgadmin that will output the number of rows from the "Trip" table. The table itself is output in cmd, the number of rows in this table is also output in cmd. But when writing a procedure and calling it, such an error comes out. I have psql version 15. How can I fix this error?

My code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE example2(INOUT _name character varying) AS $$
BEGIN
    SELECT count(*) FROM "_name";
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CALL example2(Trip)
```

Error:

```
ERROR: ERROR: The "trip" column does not exist
LINE 7: CALL example2(Trip)
```

Comment: Read [Dynamic SQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN).  Hint, this; `SELECT count(*) FROM "_name";` is not it.

Comment: Are you sure you want to embed SQL injection as core functionality in your code? People have been fired for less…

Comment: Should have added to my first comment, the error is coming from this `example2(Trip)`. Since the `_name` is unquoted it is being taken as a column name and also down cased per [Identifiers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS). The value should be entered as `'Trip'` but then the procedure would fail here, ` SELECT count(*) FROM "_name";`  with `ERROR:  relation "_name" does not exist` as the string `"_name"` is taken as the table name not the parameter value for `_name`. Hence the need for dynamic sql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are better off using a function then a procedure as it is easier to get value out. Using dynamic SQL along with the [format](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT) function to properly quote the `_name` parameter.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.example2(_name character varying)
 RETURNS integer
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
DECLARE
    ct integer;
BEGIN
    EXECUTE format('SELECT count(*) FROM %I', _name) INTO ct;
    RETURN ct;
END;
$function$


select example2('animals');
 example2 
----------
        8
```